# Как сделать правильно выборку из таблицы температур?

Tags: firebird, sql

Мне нужно сделать выборку из таблицы которая бы вывела среднесуточную температуру, на каждый день в течении года. Но есть одна загвоздка, мне результат уже в программе нужно в отчет выводить, поэтому первая строка должна быть январь, вторая февраль и т.д.
то есть должно выглядеть что то вроде :

```
            1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  ...
Январь      

Февраль

Март
....
```

Я делал очень деревянно - создал процедуру и в цикле от 1 до 12 в каждую 31 переменную и присваивал данные, но запрос очень долго выполняется, есть способ облегчить всё это?

для примера покажу свою процедуру: http://paste.org.ru/?ai1g17

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, если вопрос про базу данных, нужно указывать, какая конкретно БД, т.к. синтаксис сложных запросов может сильно различаться.
Если говорить про *MySQL*, можно использовать что-то вроде (предполагается, что `STATIONDATE` это `DATETIME`):

```
SELECT STATIONDATE, AVG(OUTSIDETEMP)
FROM WEATHER
WHERE date_time>=01.01.2011 AND STATIONDATE<=31.12.2011
GROUP BY TO_DAYS(STATIONDATE) ORDER BY STATIONDATE ASC;
```

То есть, идея в том, чтобы выбирать среднюю температуру с группировкой по суткам, т.е. средие температуры за сутки.

Comment: Выдавать результат выборки из БД напрямую в GUI почти всегда плохая идея, и работает только для простых данных. Поэтому, почти в любом случае нужна какая-то программная прослойка (конкретно с Firebird и его возможностями в этом смысле не знаком, к сожалению).
Другой выход, использовать представление, где каждое поле в каждой строке это будет отдельный запрос к базе. Опять же, представление должно будет генерироваться автоматически с помощью хитрых алгоритмов.
Третий - создать таблицу для готовых данных и заполнять ее данными из запроса, вроде моего.

Comment: хорошо как действительно умно можно сделать такой запрос - 

SELECT extract(month from STATIONDATE) as "Месяц", extract(day from STATIONDATE) as "День", avg(outsidetemp) as "Среднее значение"
FROM WEATHER WHERE STATIONDATE between '1.01.2011' and '31.12.2011' group by extract(month from STATIONDATE), extract(day from STATIONDATE)

а вот итоге что насчет представления? как там можно это хитро сделать для каждого месяца каждая строка.

Comment: Наверное, представление это все-таки плохая идея. Если выводить пользователю нужно прямо результат выборки из базы, лучше использовать промежуточную таблицу именно такого вида, какой нужен. Конечно, в эту таблицу нужно будет сначала положить данные.

Comment: Не вариант. Можно как то ну грубо говоря перевернуть таблицу в том виде в котором надо с помощью case.
Но в итоге нужно получить что то вида - http://rghost.ru/33876591.view

Comment: В любом случае, обычно для сложной обработки данных нужно что-то большее, чем встроенный язык запросов. Возможно, всетаки более правильным будет использование внешнего скрипта, который будет брать данные из базы, обрабатывать и ложить обратно в базу перед составлением отчета.
Опять же, составление запросов с 31 полем это в любом случае плохая идея.

Comment: всё это уже опробовано. я делал процедуру ссылка на которую выше. и она работает. единственный минус надо оптимизировать уж очень долго делает запрос - 21 секунду. вся проблема что сервер Pentium 2 333 mhz.  И не слово простарье и некрофилию.

Comment: Как показывает моя практика, обработка 50 тысяч строк в таблице (несколько LEFT JOIN, группировка с суммированием, сортировка, потом суммирование еще раз програмно, формирование разметки HTML для отчета с навигацией) делается примерно 30 секунд на Intel Atom 1.6GHz. База MySQL, язык программирования Python. Ну это к слову.

Comment: можно как то через case сделать 31 столбец и 12 строк?